# TCGABiolinks error: Error in names(y) <- 1:length(y) : 'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [0]

Tags: r, normalization, bioinformatics, bioconductor

Any advice about why I'm getting the error when running the normalization step in TCGABiolinks?

Comment: Some of your data appears to be empty.

Comment: It's not empty, the bioconductor code for analyzing ht-counts data is flawed.

Answer (score 3):

For me, the reason was that I first provided the wrong `geneInfo` data. In my data set, I had Ensemble IDs which were not used in the `geneInfo` data set (just enter "geneInfo" in R and you will see the table with the gene IDs).

However, `TCGAbiolinks` offers the `geneInfoHT` data set for HTSeq-Counts - with this it worked for me. My final command looked like this:

```
dataNorm <- TCGAanalyze_Normalization(tabDF = data1, geneInfoHT)
```